# Ridge Regression with glmnet for polynomial and interactions terms

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, regression

I have a data set with 9000 observations and 13 explanatory variables.

Some of them are categorical variables so I transformed them into dummies and set always one category NULL because of being the base category. Now I have already 53 explanatory variables. I want to do a ridge regression to get the best model for out-of-sample predictions. For that I want to use the `glmnet` package. Out of the 13 explanatory variables, I want to create polynomials to the degrees of 2-10 and build all possible interaction terms of the normal variables and also all polynomial variables. I also want polynomials for the interaction terms to the degrees 2-10.

My problem is that the `glmnet` package only uses matrices or data frames as arguments so I can't use formulas. If I try to produce a dataframe with all this variables I get so many columns in my data frame that my R shuts down.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `model.matrix` to specify this. Here is an example using `iris` data

First I will create a dummy factor column with some levels:

```
df <- iris
df$factor <- as.factor(sample(1:2, nrow(iris), replace = TRUE))
head(df)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species factor
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa      1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa      1
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa      1
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa      2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa      2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa      2
```

now make the model matrix

```
x <- model.matrix(Species ~ poly(Sepal.Length, 10)*factor-1, #-1 means no intercept
              data = df)
ncol(x) #output is 22, do head(x) to see what the columns are
```

basically you have 10 columns of poly for Sepal.Length interacting with the first level + 10 columns of poly for Sepal.Length interacting with the second level + two one hot columns corresponding to the factor variable.

and now use cv to find the best lambda:

```
model <- cv.glmnet(y = iris$Species,
                   x = x,
                   alpha = 0,
                   family = "multinomial",
                   lambda.min.ratio = 1e-6) #changed it from the default since it looked the optimum is lower then the min lambda tried

plot(model)
```

[image]

Comment: i allready created dummy variables with the dummy package.I also created polynomials and cbind both data sets . I have now a data frame with 70 collums and want to build all possible interactions terms. Model matrix dont work because the restult will be bigger then one gb

Comment: have you tried [`sparse.model.matrix`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/sparse.model.matrix.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite an answer - more of an explanation of why this is so difficult - but definitely too long for a comment.

First of all, lasso/ridge/elastic net methods are fundamentally built on operations on the model matrix (i.e. the matrix with one row per observation and one per *predictor* variable, i.e. variables derived from the input variables), so there's really no way around constructing the model matrix at some point (although you might be able to do it piecewise, see below).

Sparse model matrix models will help with building model matrices that mostly involve factors (which get converted to indicator or dummy variables), but I think it's not going to help you too much.

This [math overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225953/number-of-polynomial-terms-for-certain-degree-and-certain-number-of-variables) explains that a polynomial of order `n` of `k` variables requires `choose(n+k,k)` derived variables (in R terms: that's the binomial coefficient giving the number of possible samples of size `k` from `n+k` objects).  Constructing a function that reports the number of columns of the model matrix, total number of elements if there are `r` rows, and the total size (in Mb) of the model matrix:

```
calc_size <- function(deg,nvars,r=9000) {
  cc <- choose(deg+nvars,nvars)
  return(c(cc,cc*r,cc*r*8/2^20))
}
calc_size(10,13,r=9000)
```

tells you that you'd need 1.14 *million* columns, 10.2 *billion* total entries, and 77 Gb of space to store the model matrix for this problem.  That's without worrying about how much more room you need to expand categorical variables. If you really wanted to handle 53 fully numeric columns to 10th order you'd need 1.27*10^11 columns and petabytes of storage space. (Less for sparse model matrices, but combining sparse (dummy-variable) and non-sparse columns could be tricky ...)

If you really want to do this, you might be able to use the [biglasso](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=biglasso) package. The [vignette](https://github.com/YaohuiZeng/biglasso) gives an example of fitting a data set with n = 2898, p = 1,339,511 from a file-backed 31 G data set.  That's smaller than your intended set, but at least it's of the same order of magnitude (the fit takes about 51 minutes on 4 cores ...)  If I were doing this, I'd first construct my model matrix (probably in small chunks, say 500 or 1000 rows at a time) and store/concatenate the chunks in a data file on disk, then use `biglasso` to fit the model.

Depending on your available hardware and level of technical expertise, though, you might have to scale back your goals (brute force on C(10,53) columns is unlikely to work).